# drop down menu hiding behind content

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a screen that looks like this:

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.topContainer}>
          <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
            <FavoritePointInput
              textChangeHandler={textChangeHandler}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.dropdown}>
          <LocationsFound
            addressesFound={locations.favAddressesFoundList}
          />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.fieldDescription}>
            <Text>Set Location's Name:</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
            <Item style={styles.searchField}>
              <Input
                placeholder="Library"
                onChangeText={(text) => setLocationName(text)}
                style={styles.searchText}
              />
            </Item>
          </View> 
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button style={styles.button}>
              <Text>Save Location</Text>
            </Button>
          </View>
          </View>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Its Stlyes are as like this:

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
  },
  topContainer: {
    height: moderateScale(750),
  },
  topTextContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginVertical: moderateScale(15),
    height: moderateScale(30),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(30),
    paddingRight: moderateScale(30),
  },
  topMiddleContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  topMiddleText: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 40,
  },
  searchFieldContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: moderateScale(120),
  },
  button: {
    width: moderateScale(120),
    borderRadius: moderateScale(20),
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignContent: 'center',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  searchField: {
    width: moderateScale(300, 0.3),
    height: verticalScale(40),
    marginVertical: moderateScale(3),
    borderRadius: verticalScale(10),
  },
  fieldDescription: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
    dropdown:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 200,
  }
});
```

When I write something in the first input field, I get search results through the `LocationsFound` component. However, the search results start to hide behind the second input field. I want it to simply overlap and come on top of the second field until one of them is selected. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `zIndex`?

```
dropdown:{
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 200,
  zIndex: 10,
  backgroundColor: '#fff'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me I gave negative zIndex to the View which was showing on my dropdown list.

```
<View>
<DropDownPicker ... />
</View>
<View style={{ zIndex : -5 }}>
<Button ... />
<Button ... /> 
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by adding dropDownDirection="TOP" props into dropdown component which render dropdown container upside.

```
<DropDownPicker
  dropDownDirection="TOP"
  ...
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you could try is to change the order of your DOM objects and be sure to add your result as last item:

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.topContainer}>
          <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
            <FavoritePointInput
              textChangeHandler={textChangeHandler}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.fieldDescription}>
            <Text>Set Location's Name:</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
            <Item style={styles.searchField}>
              <Input
                placeholder="Library"
                onChangeText={(text) => setLocationName(text)}
                style={styles.searchText}
              />
            </Item>
          </View> 
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button style={styles.button}>
              <Text>Save Location</Text>
            </Button>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.dropdown}>
          <LocationsFound
            addressesFound={locations.favAddressesFoundList}
          />
          </View>
          </View>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Another solution could be to add a z-index to your dropDown:

```
    fieldDescription: {
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
        dropdown:{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 200,
        zIndex: 1 // ... or more  
}
```